# How to increment a variable name by 1 in Lua, and then set that as the variable name?

Tags: variables, lua, repeat

My current code is:

```
obj1 = object:new{x = math.random(1,92), y = math.random(1,92), roomx = 0, roomy = 0, symbol = "t", name = "Tree"}  
obj2 = object:new{x = math.random(1,92), y = math.random(1,92), roomx = 0, roomy = 0, symbol = "t", name = "Tree"}  
obj3 = object:new{x = math.random(1,92), y = math.random(1,92), roomx = 0, roomy = 0, symbol = "t", name = "Tree"}
```

And so on. Since they are all the same thing, I'd like to be able to generate a variable that I can increment the name by one, and then use a for loop to create a lot of them. Is there a way I can do that in Lua? Thanks!

Comment: Use a table and a for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a table to hold the objects and add them using a for loop.

```
local objects = {}

--> This will create 20 objects
for i=1, 20 do
    objects[i] = object:new{x = math.random(1,92), y = math.random(1,92), roomx = 0, roomy = 0, symbol = "t", name = "Tree"}
end
```